# buttons not changing colour of background and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm apparently doing something wrong with this code. Not sure what but its going really wrong.

I'm wanting it so that when you click a button the colour the background and the text changes font, Currently not happening

```
<style>
.red { background-color: red; }
.red p { font-style: normal; }

.blue { background-color: blue; }
.blue p { font-style: italic; }

.green { background-color: green; }
.green p { font-style: oblique;}
</style>
<div ng-class={{colorScheme}}>

    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'red'">ColorScheme Red</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'blue'">ColorScheme Blue</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'green'">ColorScheme Green</button>

    <p>Awesome content</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the scope variable to `ng-class` like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.red p {
  font-style: normal;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.blue p {
  font-style: italic;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.green p {
  font-style: oblique;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div ng-class="colorScheme">
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'red'">ColorScheme Red</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'blue'">ColorScheme Blue</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'green'">ColorScheme Green</button>
    <p>Awesome content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm!! haah!

Answer (score 1):

If you use ng-class don't put expressions{{}} just use directly the scope object. Because its default directive in angular they didn't expect the expressions {{}}

Otherwise Use class with expression in the way of I am answered

```
<div class="{{colorScheme}}">

    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'red'">ColorScheme Red</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'blue'">ColorScheme Blue</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'green'">ColorScheme Green</button>

    <p>Awesome content</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Add the " and this is perfect (http://plnkr.co/edit/xMq1ExoUPGotgxFTVMdM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged JQuery...
this works for me:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('color'));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7kq8qxyq/) :)

Comment: This is a good answer, but till he is using angular, he shouldn't use jQuery within angular (Can create a lot of issues).

Comment: @Okazari I agree :) I just wanted to do it the JQuery way for fun since it was tagged :D Cheers :D

Comment: That's why it's still a good answer. Just wanted to put a warning for the angular users reading this :)